# Entity Framework 6 with MySQL - Class Library

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a project in visual studio (web MVC app) linked to a MySQL database with EF6. Everything is working, I have the provider referenced on web.config, everything is correct. Now I want to separate the Data access to a new project of type class library. I created the project, added the references (MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6), added the provider to the app.config, I think I did all the steps, but I'm stuck when I try to create a new data context with the error below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="dPhotos.data.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.teste.csdl|res://*/Models.teste.ssdl|res://*/Models.teste.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=###############;user id=#############;password=############;database=###########&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <userSettings>
    <dPhotos.data.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="fdsgd" serializeAs="String">
        <value>fdgd</value>
      </setting>
    </dPhotos.data.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

On your machine where Visual Studio, MySQL VS plugin and Connector/Net are installed:

- close all VS instances before doing the steps.
- on a Windows Explorer window go to this path or wherever you installed you Connector/NET binaries:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net {version}\Assemblies\v4.5\
  ```
- copy the file `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll` and paste it to this folder:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {version}\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
  ```

  (if it asks you to overwrite it please do so. You'll need admin rights in order to overwrite the file.)
- add reference to this DLL in the project.

Then you can try again to generate the script for your model.

Your app.config should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dPhotosEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dPhotosModel.csdl|res://*/Models.dPhotosModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.dPhotosModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;password=######;user id=######;server=######;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=######&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```